# How can I let a script parse content from next pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape three fields from different companies listed in a webpage. The idea here is to make use of this [webpage](https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings), parse the inner page links of different companies from the landing page and finally scrape `title`,`phone` and `email` from the detail pages. The script that I've created can perform this without any issue.

However, I wish to scrape content from next pages (`Next`) as well. As I'm very new to node, I would appreciate if somebody could help me implement the logic of grabbing next pages within the script below.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const base = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com";
const url = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings";

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    page.waitForSelector(".company-listing");
    const sections = await page.$$(".company-listing");
    let data = [];
    for (const section of sections) {
        const itemName = await section.$eval("h3 > a", el => el.getAttribute("href"));
        data.push(itemName);
    }
    let itmdata = [];
    for (const link of data) {
        const newlink = base.concat(link);
        await page.goto(newlink,{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
        page.waitForSelector(".company-details");
        const result = await page.$$(".company-details");

        for (const itmres of result) {
            const company = await itmres.$eval("h3", el => el.textContent);
            const phone = await itmres.$eval("#valuephone a[href]", el => el.textContent);
            const email = await itmres.$eval("a[onclick^='showCompanyEmail']", el => el.getAttribute("onclick"));
            console.log({
                title: company,
                tel : phone.trim(),
                emailId : email.split("('")[1].split("',")[0]
            });
        }
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

> How can I implement the logic of traversing next pages within the script?

EDIT:

I was trying to use the next page link within [the script](https://pastebin.com/rKJ2mQNG) ***iteratively*** defining a [while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogxXp.jpg). This time the script however doesn't seem to respond at all. Perhaps I've done something wrong along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you declare new `url` variable in each iteration. Instead of this, you need to declare the outer `url` variable as `let` and redefine it:

```js
let url = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings";
// ...
        url = base.concat(nextPageLink);
```